# SSIS Debug run in wrong working directory

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I have come across a problem when I make an SSIS package deployment model.

When I debug my package if I have a FileConnection how refer to a another package (with relative path), the file will not be found because my debug working directory is set as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn".
And of course my file is not there.

Normally, in debug in Visual Studio the working directory in debug is "$(SolutionDir)/bin/debug" or in this case "$(SolutionDir)/bin/Development".
I have looked a lot to solve this issue without founding any solution.

I have a coworker, for which this problem didn't occur, he can debug my project without issue, so I'm sure the problem comes from my visual studio or my installed extension. But I can find how to solve this.

I have to always use relative path in my project and must not change the project way to get the path of the file.

I have already reinstalled VS. and SSIS, check if is an issue of the writ, copy the file in the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn" and then it work.

But normally the working directory must be the "$(SolutionDir)/bin/Development".